# Adding Additional Contact Phone Numbers to a Task

Tags: apex, trigger, loop

I am in need of adding additional phone numbers from a Contact onto the Task that the contact is associated to. I have coded the following trigger however the code seems to only work with one of the tel numbers and presents a msg that the other variables dont exist. Following is my code any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

```
trigger ConHomeTelNumberOnTask on Task (before insert, before update) {
Map<Id, List<Task>> whoIds = new Map<Id, List<Task>>{};

For (Task t : trigger.new)
    If(t.WhoId != null){
        List<Task> tasks = whoIds.get(t.WhoId); //this should be t.WhoId (not task.WhoId)
        If (tasks == null){
        tasks = new List<Task>{};
        whoIds.put(t.WhoId, tasks);
    }
    tasks.add(t);
}

For(Contact con : [Select Id, Name, HomePhone, Best_Tel__c, Business_Phone__c, MobilePhone, McLabs2__Verified__c  from Contact where Id in :whoIds.keySet()])
    For(Task t : whoIds.get(con.id))
        t.Home_Phone__c = con.HomePhone;
        //t.Best_Tel__c = con.Best_Tel__c;
        //t.Business_Phone__c = con.Business_Phone__c;
        //t.Mobile_Phone__c = con.MobilePhone;
        //t.Verified__c = con.McLabs2__Verified__c;
```

}

If I un-comment the other phone number the error msg is presented.

Answer (score 2):

Not certain this is the problem, or if it is a copy-paste ommission.

These are single-line for loops as written:

```
For(Contact con : [Select Id, etc....])
   For(Task t : whoIds.get(con.id))
      t.Home_Phone__c = con.HomePhone;
      //t.Best_Tel__c = con.Best_Tel__c;
      //t.Business_Phone__c = con.Business_Phone__c;
      //t.Mobile_Phone__c = con.MobilePhone;
      //t.Verified__c = con.McLabs2__Verified__c;
```

In order for your for loop to evaluate multiple lines, you must create a code block with `{}`

So maybe this will work?

```
For(Contact con : [Select Id, etc....]) {  //<=open code block
   For(Task t : whoIds.get(con.id)) {  //<=open code block
      t.Home_Phone__c = con.HomePhone;
      //t.Best_Tel__c = con.Best_Tel__c;
      //t.Business_Phone__c = con.Business_Phone__c;
      //t.Mobile_Phone__c = con.MobilePhone;
      //t.Verified__c = con.McLabs2__Verified__c;

   ...
   }  //<= Don't for get to close it
}  //<= and here
```

This would explain why the `variable does not exist` error message, too, as without the code block, by the time `t.Best_Tel__c = con.Best_Tel__c;` executes, technically, you've left the scope of the `for` loops, so both `t` and `con` are out of scope.

Comment: @Carl marking an answer as the correct answer will take it out of the "unanswered" questions. You also reward others with points. All part of the fun of StackExchange. It also helps others reading your question know how it was resolved at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your Task List variable within your FOR Loop, which means it is only available within the FOR Loop.

You should declare it as a Trigger variable by instantiating your Task List before you enter your FOR loop.

I've revised the code:

```
trigger ConHomeTelNumberOnTask on Task (before insert, before update) { 

Map> whoIds = new Map>{};
List<Task> tasks = whoIds.get(t.WhoId); //this should be t.WhoId (not task.WhoId)

For (Task t : trigger.new)
If(t.WhoId != null){

    If (tasks == null){
    tasks = new List<Task>{};
    whoIds.put(t.WhoId, tasks);
}
tasks.add(t);
}

For(Contact con : [Select Id, Name, HomePhone, Best_Tel__c, Business_Phone__c, MobilePhone, McLabs2__Verified__c  from Contact where Id in :whoIds.keySet()])
    For(Task t : whoIds.get(con.id))
        t.Home_Phone__c = con.HomePhone;
        //t.Best_Tel__c = con.Best_Tel__c;
        //t.Business_Phone__c = con.Business_Phone__c;
        //t.Mobile_Phone__c = con.MobilePhone;
        //t.Verified__c = con.McLabs2__Verified__c;
}
```